# innerHTML image syntax for randomized image?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use a button click to randomly display an image and text. My current code works to randomise the name display, but the image comes up broken. What is the correct syntax for having the image from random display div `id=target`?

```html
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Randomize" onclick="GetValue();" />
<br>
<img id="target" src="/img/test.png">
<p id="message" > test </p>

<script>
const btn = document.querySelector("#btnSearch");

function GetValue()
{
    var quotes        = [
            { 
    name: "Roller Coaster",
    img: "/img/emojibase/rollercoaster.png",
  },
            { 
    name: "Rooster",
    img: "/img/emojibase/rooster.png",
  },
            { 
    name: "Rose",
    img: "/img/emojibase/rose.png",
  }
    ];   

    var random = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];

    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = random.name;
    document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = random.img;
}

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    GetValue();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of the *innerHTML* you should use the *src* attribute of the image element.

**Change:**

```
document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = random.img;
```

**To:**

```
document.getElementById("target").src = random.img;
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Randomize" onclick="GetValue();" />
<br>
<img id="target" src="/img/test.png">
<p id="message" > test </p>

<script>
  const btn = document.querySelector("#btnSearch");

  function GetValue()
  {
      var quotes        = [
              { 
      name: "Roller Coaster",
      img: "/img/emojibase/rollercoaster.png",
    },
              { 
      name: "Rooster",
      img: "/img/emojibase/rooster.png",
    },
              { 
      name: "Rose",
      img: "/img/emojibase/rose.png",
    }
      ];   

      var random = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];

      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = random.name;
      document.getElementById("target").src = random.img;
  }

  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      GetValue();
  });
</script>
```